# How to set show_grid = True as a global option in holoviews?

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

I can always set the show_grid = True in the holoviews with bokeh as a backend

```
plt = hv.Curve((x,y))
plt.options(width=600,height=400,xlabel='time in sec', ylabel='volts',show_grid=True,title='Myplot')
```

I was wondering if this can be set as true globally for all or most types of plots like curve, scatter etc.

[Plotted using holoviews, with show_grid=True, backend is bokeh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrWRU.png)

Comment: It looks like the defaults are set in [#L170 of the init for bokeh](https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/blob/c425b5546adeb55bef5c34ed08343b69df0ca35b/holoviews/plotting/bokeh/__init__.py#L170). Maybe you can adapt it here.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, mosc9575!
Following your suggestion, this worked for me. 
Posting complete example if someone needs it

```
import holovivews as hv
import numpy as np

hv.opts.defaults(hv.opts.Scatter(height=400, width=900 ,show_grid=True, size=4))

x,y = np.random.randn(2,100)
hv.Scatter((x,y))
```

[image: Scatter plot with grid on by default]